# VMware Workstation: Bridge to Wireless NIC will not route traffic to wireless AP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vmware-workstation, bridge

I'm running VMware Workstation 12.5, but have seen the same symptoms in 12.0 as well. The host OS is Windows 10 Pro version 1511. I've tried several versions of Windows as guest OSs, and seen the same results with all of them.

If I use the VMware Virtual Network Editor to select my laptop's Ethernet adapter (Intel Ethernet Connection I219-LM) as the bridging NIC, and set my guest VM's Network Adapter to Bridged, it works perfectly.

When I select my laptop's wireless adapter (Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260) as the bridging adapter, the guest VM successfully acquires an IP address and default gateway settings from the wireless AP, via DHCP. But when I try to *ping* the default gateway, I get a mix of `Reply from <guest's IP address>: Destination host unreachable` and `Request timed out` responses. I *can* successfully ping the host's IP from the guest; it's just the wireless gateway which I can't reach. Meanwhile, the host OS is using this exact same wireless network to reach the internet with no problems.

When I set the virtual network adapter to NAT, I can connect the guest to the network perfectly fine, but I want bridging so I can accept inbound connections to the VM.

The wireless access point I'm using right now is a [Telstra Mobile Wi-Fi 4G (MF91) device, manufactured by ZTE](http://www.zte.com.au/telstra/MF91.htm). It provides access to an LTE broadband connection through an 802.11 interface. However I've experience similar partial connectivity when bridging VMs to the office wireless APs as well, so I suspect the problem is more likely to be in the host NIC or VMware.

Any ideas if/how it's possible to get this bridge to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

I signed up just to reply to this. I have been banging my head all day trying to troubleshoot the same issue. I have a Lenovo Y700 with and Intel AC8260, Windows 10 Pro 1607, VM W 12.5. Just like you, if I setup bridged adapter using WiFi, the guest gets an IP from DHCP, I can ping the guest IP from anywhere on the network, but the guest traffic (TCP and ICMP) doesn't even reach the gateway. Strangely enough, it looks like UDP traffic works as the logs on my router show DNS requests from the guest VM passing through. If I switch the bridging to the Ethernet port everything works.

The issue seems to be related to some incompatibility between VMWare bridge driver and the AC8260 driver. I tried playing around with the advanced settings of the wifi adapter, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it's not just me. Doesn't get us much closer to a solution though. Might be time to contact VMware tech support directly.

Comment: I posted in the VMW Workstation forum where I found another user with the same issue using another Intel AC adapter.